# update a database row using a button

Tags: javascript, mysql, ajax, pdo, sql-update

I'm trying to update a row in my phpmyadmin database when I click on the approve button that is associated with that row

Here's the row i'm trying to approve:

> 1 , star name = question- who asked [approve button] [disapprove
>   button]

Here's my db_replicator.php:

```
    <?php
include("db_conn.php");
$sql = "update questions set approved = 1 where questionID = ?";
$qc = $pdo_conn->prepare($sql);
$qc->execute(array($_POST['questionID']));
echo 'saved';
?>
```

This is the function on the top of my views.php:

```
<script src="http://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.10.1.min.js"></script>
    <script>
        function save_a(id){
            $.post('db_replicator.php', {questionID:id}, function(result) { 
               alert(result); 
               window.location.reload();
            });
        }
    </script>
```

Here's the code I have so far on my views.php:

```
echo "<br><b>new questions: {$row4['count']}</b><br>";
while ($row44 = $prep44->fetch(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC)) {
echo "{$row44['questionID']} , {$row44['starName']} = {$row44['question']} - {$row44['whoAsked']}  
   <button onclick='save_a({$row44['questionID']})'></button><button>Disapprove</button><br>";
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think you have some misunderstanding with server and client side code.

Js runs on client machine, while PHP is server-side.
You need to run ajax request to your php code, which will save your row to db.

You can do the following:

db_replicator.php:

```
include("db_conn.php");
$sql = "update questions set approved = 1 where questionID = ?";
$qc = $pdo_conn->prepare($sql);
$qc->execute(array($_POST['questionID']));
echo 'saved';
```

your js on page in save_a function pass id of a row:

```
function save_a(id){
    $.post('db_replicator.php', { questionID: id }, function(result) { 
       alert(result); 
    });
}
```

change your button code:

```
echo "{$row44['questionID']} , {$row44['starName']} = {$row44['question']} - {$row44['whoAsked']}  
    <button onClick=save_a($row44['questionID']);'>Approve</button><button>Disapprove</button><br>";
```

Comment: oh ok I see that would explain my button isn't doing anything, I haven't used ajax before, would you please be able to help me with it?

Comment: @babyoth please, refer to documentation on post in jquery http://api.jquery.com/jQuery.post/ . If you still have questions - you are free to ask in new question. Please, accept this answers if it solves your question for other people, who searches the same problem can easily find a solution

Comment: yes i will accept the answer once i have it sorted trying it now, unsure where to put this part though: $.post('db_replicator.php', { questionID: 5 }, function(result) { 
   alert(result); 
});

Comment: I just tested it and the button still doesn't appear to be doing anything. I have edited my code above, have I done something wrong or missed anything out?

Comment: Is this part wrong <button onClick='function('save_a')>Approve</button> ?

Comment: @babyoth you should have something like:
`<button onClick="save_a(5)">Approve</button>`

Comment: I have this error, under the console panel on firebug/chrome's one and opera's one aswell: Uncaught ReferenceError: $ is not defined $.post('response4.php', { questionID: id }, function(result) { any ideas on how to fix this error? then I think it will work

Comment: @babyoth add jquery file to your js file

Comment: ahhh that's what was missing I used this one: `<script src="http://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.10.1.min.js"></script>`. It's working now :-) thanks. a part from it's not refreshing on it's own so I added this line: `window.location.reload();` I have edited my code snippets above